# How to upload mp4 with Uploadify and/or allow mp4 upload in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, video, file-upload, uploadify

I am working on an application where we've been uploading .wmv and .jpg with Uploadify.  I've added feature to allow .mp4 upload and everything works fine when uploading locally, but not to the server.  In IIS I have added the MIME type of video/mp4 for .mp4 files in every applicable folder, and can *play* the files fine (when added manually)... but for some reason I can not *upload* the .mp4 files with Uploadify to my server.  Here is the jQuery / javascript code:

```
  $('#fileInput').uploadify({
            'uploader': 'uploadify/uploadify.swf',
            'script': './Upload.ashx',
            'cancelImg': 'uploadify/cancel.png',
            'auto': false,
            'multi': true,
            'fileExt': '*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.wmv;*.mp4',
            'fileDesc': 'Allowed Files (.JPG, .JPEG, .WMV, .MP4)',
            'queueSizeLimit': 3,
            'sizeLimit': 999999999,
            'buttonText': 'Browse Files',
            'onError': function(event, ID, fileObj, errorObj) {
                alert(errorObj.type + ' Error: ' + errorObj.info);
            },
            'onComplete': function(event, ID, fileObj, response, data) {
                fileNames += fileObj.name + ',';
            },
            'onAllComplete': function(event, data) {
                if (data.errors == 0) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        data: $.toJSON({
                            Name: $("[id$='txt_Name']").val(),
                            FileNames: fileNames,
                            Active: $("[id$='rdo_ActiveYes']")[0].checked,
                            Department: $("[id$='ddl_Department']").val(),
                            Category: $("[id$='ddl_Category']").val(),
                            Description: $("[id$='txt_Description']").val()
                            //YouTubeURL: $("[id$='txt_YouTubeURL']").val()


                        }),
                        url: "WebMethods.aspx/InsertVideo",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function(results) {
                            document.location.href = "./AddVideo.aspx";
                        },
                        error: function(xhr, status, errorThrown) {
                            alert(xhr.responseText);
                        }
                    });
                }
                else {
                    alert('There was an error uploading the files; process will be aborted');
                }
            }

        });
```

I've restarted IIS (6.0) after adding the MIME type and ensured that the file size is not too large.  I'm still able to upload .jpg and .wmv fine.  Do I need to allow an 'upload file type' in IIS anywhere?  Or is there something else I'm missing? Please let me know if any additional information is needed.

EDIT:  The error I get from Uploadify is "HTTP Error: 500"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

deebs,

I would check the write access of the files on the destination server.  For example if you're attempting to overwrite an existing file that is "readonly" it may give you an error.

Comment: Thanks @mint!  It actually was not marked as "readonly", but there was a security message that says "This file came from another computer and might be blocked to help protect this computer." ... all videos that I manually added to that folder had that message.  I deleted and then uploaded from my application and that did the trick.